# Google Sheets = ImportXML number from website

Tags: xml, google-sheets-formula

I'm not a programmer but i'm trying to pull just 1 number into my google sheet.

I have tried different variations of the following with no luck:

```
= ImportXML ("https://grayscale.co/bitcoin-trust/", "// td [@ class = '"key">Bitcoin per Share<']")
```

It's located here: https://grayscale.co/bitcoin-trust/

And the number is here:

```
<tr>
  </td><td class="key">Bitcoin per Share</td>
  <td>0.00096719‡</td>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to retrieve `0.00096719‡` from `<tr><td class="key">Bitcoin per Share</td><td>0.00096719‡</td></tr>` of the URL of `https://grayscale.co/bitcoin-trust/`.
- You want to put the retrieved value to a cell of Google Spreadsheet using `IMPORTXML()`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[../td[@class='key' and text()='Bitcoin per Share']][2]")
```

- In this case, please put the URL of `https://grayscale.co/bitcoin-trust/` to the cell "A1".
- In this xpath of `//td[../td[@class='key' and text()='Bitcoin per Share']][2]`, the 2nd tag of the td tags, which have td`class="key"` and `Bitcoin per Share`, is retrieved.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- In above URL, I think that `=IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[../td[text()='Bitcoin per Share']][2]")` can also be used.
- When you want to retrieve only the value of `0.00096719` as the number, please use the following sample formula.

  ```
  =VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(A1,"//td[../td[@class='key' and text()='Bitcoin per Share']][2]"),"‡",""))
  ```

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.